# countdown timer stop not working

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I am using a countdown timer in my page which is working fine . i tried to make code for stop button but the logic doesnt seems to be working 
here is my code

```
$('.Stop').click('click', function() {
  clearTimeout( myTimer);
});

function calltimer() {
  countdown( "countdown", 1, 5 );
}


function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds ) {
  var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time,myTimer ;

  function twoDigits( n ) {
      return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
  }

  function updateTimer() {
      msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
      if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
          element.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";
      } else {
          time = new Date( msLeft );
          hours = time.getUTCHours();
          mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
          element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
          myTimer =setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
      }
  }

  element = document.getElementById( elementName );
  endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
  updateTimer();
}
```

i tried setInterval which is not seems to be work

```
$('.Stop').click('click', function() {
    setInterval(updateWCTime, 1000);
});
```

and this code

```
$('.Stop').click('click', function() {
  clearTimeout( updateTimer);
});
```

Need some suggestion , thanks

Comment: updated the code on this line  "myTimer =setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to use `clearTimeout`.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() { console.log("Hi!"); }, 5000);
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

About your countdown timer, I think you should use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead.

Comment: i have part of this code in update timer . should i update at that point

Comment: Your "myTimer" should be declared outside the "countdown" function, because the button click function does not know the "myTimer" variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `myTimer` is a **local** variable of your `updateTimer()` function. It is undefined within the click handler scope. Thus, you could use global variable instead, see runnable example below.

```js
var myTimer;

$('.Stop').click('click', function() {
  clearTimeout(myTimer);
});

function calltimer() {
  countdown( "countdown", 1, 5 );
}

function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds ) {
  var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time ;

  function twoDigits( n ) {
      return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
  }

  function updateTimer() {
      msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
      if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
          element.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";
      } else {
          time = new Date( msLeft );
          hours = time.getUTCHours();
          mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
          element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
          myTimer =setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
      }
  }

  element = document.getElementById( elementName );
  endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
  updateTimer();
}

countdown("counter", 1, 30);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="counter"></p>
<button class="Stop" type="button">Stop</button>
```